# Calculating water mask over a large data set

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, function

I'm calculating a water mask with OTSU over an Image Collection with a large time frame, so the dataset is very large. When I shorten the time frame, it works. For the larger time frame, I get this error:

> Error in
> map(ID=S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20180807T181915_20180807T181932_023144_028393_EB24):
> Dictionary.get: Dictionary does not contain key: bucketMeans.

I think my bug could be in the water mask function. Maybe it's because of the reduceRegion, but I don't understand why, since I map each image to the function.

```
function function_water_mask(img) {
  
  var histogram = img.select('VV').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram()
      .combine('mean', null, true)
      .combine('variance', null, true), 
    geometry: threshold, 
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  var thres = otsu(histogram.get('VV' + '_histogram'));
  
  var water_mask = img.select("VV").lt(thres).copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames());

  var add_prop = water_mask.set({'Thres': thres});           

  return ee.Image(add_prop);
}
```

Here is the complete GEE script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/bb186206ae9f578e1c7c7ca2f8415778

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With the hints from the previous answer, I found the problem why I was getting error images. It was due to the geometry in the function "function_water_mask". The histogram was calculated only for the "threshold" layer. The error image had no values because the layer and the image did not overlap. So the solution was to add another polygon to the "threshold" layer.

The code is the same as above, only the "threshold" layer has one more polygon now. That's why the solution has nothing to do with the code. The code was right.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/94dacf9b91af8354c8ac6621c667a482

Comment: Please remember to always include the relevant bock of code in your Answer.

Answer (score 3):

I modified your function as follows for only retrieving "bucketMeans".

```
function function_water_mask(img) {
  
  var histogram = ee.Image(img).select('VV').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram()
      .combine('mean', null, true)
      .combine('variance', null, true), 
    geometry: threshold, 
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  var thres = otsu(histogram.get('VV' + '_histogram'));
  
  var water_mask = ee.Image(img).select("VV").lt(thres).copyProperties(ee.Image(img), ee.Image(img).propertyNames());

  var add_prop = water_mask.set({'Thres': thres});           

  return histogram.get('VV_histogram');
}

var s1_lst = s1.toList(s1.size());

// Water Mask with function:
var s1_water_mask = s1_lst.map(function_water_mask);
//print('water mask', s1_water_mask);
//Map.addLayer(s1_water_mask.map(function(img){return img.clip(area);}), vis_waterMask, 'Water mask', false);

var lst = ee.List.sequence(0, s1_water_mask.size().subtract(49));

print(lst);

var bucketMeans =  lst.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Dictionary(s1_water_mask.get(ele)).get('bucketMeans');
  
});

print("bucketMeans", bucketMeans);
```

Your image collection has 242 images but element corresponding to 194 (or any other image until 242) has not "bucketMeans". For this reason you have that error message with entire collection.

My complete code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1b155ae8a4a7918ae38d72cb22f013e8). After running it in GEE code editor, I only can get 194 "bucketMeans", not the expected 242 elements in that series; as it can be observed in following image.

[image]

If all images had "bucketMeans", the subtract number in following instruction should be 1; not 49. You need to find out a method for detecting this anomaly in your collection.

```
var lst = ee.List.sequence(0, s1_water_mask.size().subtract(49));
```

**Editing Note 1:**

I found out that your image collection has only one image without "bucketMeans": 194. So, adding following lines in your original code:

```
var s1_lst = s1.toList(s1.size()).slice(0, 194);
var s2_lst = s1.toList(s1.size()).slice(195, 242);

print(s1_lst.size(), s2_lst.size());

s1 = ee.ImageCollection(s1_lst.cat(s2_lst));
```

it produces ([link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/fb475698661e9a07b02afdda774f5a43)) corresponding 241 water masks without any error; as it can be observed in following image:

[image]

**Editing Note 2:**

Following version of your code ([link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f35e12ec7754840cc5e1e865005f74cb)) automatically detect bad images and remove them from complete collection. Main changes are as follow:

```
var s1_list = s1.toList(s1.size());

var histogram = s1_list.map(function (img) {
  
  var histogram = ee.Image(img).select('VV').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram()
      .combine('mean', null, true)
      .combine('variance', null, true), 
    geometry: threshold, 
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  var thres = otsu(histogram.get('VV' + '_histogram'));
  
  var water_mask = ee.Image(img).select("VV").lt(thres).copyProperties(ee.Image(img), ee.Image(img).propertyNames());

  var add_prop = water_mask.set({'Thres': thres});           

  return histogram.get('VV_histogram');

});

//print("histogram", histogram);

var validIndices = histogram.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(ele, histogram.indexOf(ele), null);
  
}, true);

//print(validIndices);

var count = histogram.size();

var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, count.subtract(1));

var nullIndices = sequence.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(validIndices.contains(ele), 0, ele);
  
}).removeAll([0]);

print('nullIndices', nullIndices);

var wrongImages = nullIndices.map(function (ele) {
  
  return s1_list.get(ele);
  
});

print("wrongImages", wrongImages);

function function_water_mask(img) {
  
  var histogram = img.select('VV').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram()
      .combine('mean', null, true)
      .combine('variance', null, true), 
    geometry: threshold, 
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  var thres = otsu(histogram.get('VV' + '_histogram'));
  
  var water_mask = img.select("VV").lt(thres).copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames());

  var add_prop = water_mask.set({'Thres': thres});           

  return ee.Image(add_prop);
}

var s1_new_list = s1_list.removeAll(wrongImages);

s1 = ee.ImageCollection(s1_new_list);

// Water Mask with function:
var s1_water_mask = s1.map(function_water_mask);
print('water mask', s1_water_mask);
Map.addLayer(s1_water_mask.map(function(img){return img.clip(area);}), vis_waterMask, 'Water mask', false);
```

Running it in GEE code editor occurs without any error; as in following picture.

[image]

Comment: Please don't leave "thanks" comments. This is covered in the [Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) -- *Thanks and other statements of appreciation are unnecessary, and, like other chitchat, should not be included.*